# Pasar datos de una tabla en HTML a un insert en Mysql con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, insert

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Lo que sucede es que tengo una tabla en HTML que estoy generando con javascript, pero el resultado que me da, la debo guardar en una tabla que tengo en mi BD

Tabla HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente recorriendo la tabla y generando un array, mi resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero despues de eso, no logro hacer el insert con Ajax, no encuentro la manera de recibir los datos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Aqui pongo el codigo con el que tomo los datos de la tabla y el envio por ajax:

```
valores=new Array();
  $('#table-2 tr').each(function () {
    var cuotaNo= $(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
    var interes = $(this).find('td').eq(1).html();
    var abonoCapital = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
    var valorCuota = $(this).find('td').eq(3).html();
    var saldoCapital = $(this).find('td').eq(4).html();
    valor=new Array(cuotaNo, interes, abonoCapital, valorCuota, saldoCapital);
    valores.push(valor);
    console.log (valor);
    $.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: "POST",
     url: "crud/register-payment-plan.php",
     data: {valores:valores},
     success: function(data) { if(data!="");}
    });
   });
```

Base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo PHP:

```
    <?php


list($cuotaNo, $interes, $abonoCapital, $valorCuota, $saldoCapital) = explode(",",$_POST["valores"]);


include_once "../connection/connection.php";


$sql = "INSERT INTO payment_plan (loan_id, fee_number, tentative_payment_date, payment_date_applied, fee_value, pending_value, state) VALUES ('16', '$cuotaNo', '2018-10-10', '$dates', '$valorCuota', '$saldoCapital', 'pendiente')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        // header('Location: ../loans.php?registrationstatus=true');
    echo "Si registro";
} else {
        // header('Location: ../loans.php?registrationstatus=false');
    echo "No registro";
}
?>
```

Comment: ayudanos poniendo el codigo que tienes cuando la recorres y el de ajax

Comment: Listo!! se me había olvidado, mil gracias.

Comment: saca el ajax de lala funcion `each` y prueba

Comment: No, en realidad lo tengo asi para que por cada registro mande un array con el fin de guardar todos, si lo saco solo guarda uno, pero el verdadero problema es que no se como recibir esos datos, subi una imagen de los registros que hago en base de datos y el codigo de PHP, no me trae los parametros y los que hay en la tabla, son quemados

Comment: Bueno, siendo asi, la respuesta de abajo si te servira, donde concatena los dotos y los envia por separado

Comment: Te recomiendo usar un ORM como Doctrine, para evitar inyección de código y haga mas fácil el manejo con la base de datos.

Comment: Con ese código `async: false` harás una petición (AJAX), y un `INSERT` en la base de datos **por cada fila** que hay, te sugiero por razones de rendimiento que lo reduzcas a 1 llamada al terminar de generar un objeto enviarlo todo junto, las bases de datos relacionales (MySQL) no están hechas para tanta carga en tan poco tiempo. En especial si deseas escalarla en un futuro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

siguiendo tu logica y tus intenciones, veo que lo que necesitas es esto:

```
$('#table-2 tr').each(function () {
    var cuotaNo= $(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
    var interes = $(this).find('td').eq(1).html();
    var abonoCapital = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
    var valorCuota = $(this).find('td').eq(3).html();
    var saldoCapital = $(this).find('td').eq(4).html();

    $.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: "POST",
     url: "crud/register-payment-plan.php",
        data: "cuotaNo="+cuotaNo+"&interes="+interes+"&abonoCapital="+abonoCapital+"&valorCuota="+valorCuota+"&saldoCapital="+saldoCapital,
     data: {valores:valores},
     success: function(data) { if(data!="");}
    });
   });
```

en tu archivo de php:

```
  <?php
   include_once "../connection/connection.php";

    $cuotaNo = $_POST['cuotaNo'];
    $interes = $_POST['interes'];
    $abonoCapital = $_POST['abonoCapital'];
    $valorCuota = $_POST['valorCuota'];
    $saldoCapital = $_POST['saldoCapital'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO payment_plan (loan_id, fee_number, tentative_payment_date, payment_date_applied, fee_value, pending_value, state) VALUES ('16', '$cuotaNo', '2018-10-10', '$dates', '$valorCuota', '$saldoCapital', 'pendiente')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            // header('Location: ../loans.php?registrationstatus=true');
        echo "Si registro";
    } else {
            // header('Location: ../loans.php?registrationstatus=false');
        echo "No registro";
    }

?>
```

**NOTA**: tenga en cuenta que de esta forma estaria haciendo tantas peticiones como filas tenga la tabla:

ya en el archivo php las captura normalmente como una variable `$_POS['nombre']`

Comment: Pero en realidad mando varios array, no es solo uno lo que lo complica un poco

Comment: por eso te sugeria que sacaras el ajax del each, y un mas debes explicar que quieres enviar mas cosas atraves de ese array :)

Comment: que mas datos envias ahi =?

Comment: No, solo era eso y si funciono :D

Comment: Bueno, me alegro mucho, poder ayudarte... :)

Comment: Aprovecho para hacer una pregunta, y es que yo aparte de los datos que estoy enviando, también debo enviar el valor de un input que tengo más arriba, ya capturo el valor pero no se como hacer que el POST lo toma

Comment: lo caputas y lo concatenas de la misma forma que te puse los otros

Comment: lo caputas y lo concatenas de la misma forma que te puse los otros

Answer (score 1):

Primero, me parece ineficiente hacer un request por cada fila. Entre otras cosas porque la única manera de controlar el bucle es realizar pedidas síncronas, lo cual es un método que se contrapone con el propósito de ajax.

Segundo, tu tabla necesita tener un `thead` y un `tbody` para evitar buscar elementos `td` en donde van las cabeceras `th` (resultando en un array vacío).

Tercero, yo declararía un array, ejecutaría el bucle y en cada iteración iría **añadiendo a ese array un objeto**, de manera que no tuvieses que confiar en el orden en que se envían las columnas ni asumir que nunca cambiarán. El objeto ya tiene las llaves y eso te va a servir mucho.

Entonces:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#enviar').on('click', function() {
    var filas = [];
    $('#table-2 tbody tr').each(function() {
      var cuotano = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
      var interes = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
      var abonocapital = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
      var valorcuota = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text();
      var saldocapital = $(this).find('td').eq(4).text();

      var fila = {
        cuotano,
        interes,
        abonocapital,
        valorcuota,
        saldocapital
      };
      filas.push(fila);
    });
    console.log(filas);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="table-2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Cuota No.</th>
          <th>Interés </th>
          <th>Abono al Capital</th>
          <th>Valor cuota</th>
          <th>Saldo al Capital</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>36364</td>
          <td>57037</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>553073</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>29456</td>
          <td>63945</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>622957</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17136</td>
          <td>76265</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>581032</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>22617</td>
          <td>70784</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>730122</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>39457</td>
          <td>53944</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>745940</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>17447</td>
          <td>75954</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>555536</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>23146</td>
          <td>70255</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>754439</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>15335</td>
          <td>78066</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>536352</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>27797</td>
          <td>65604</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>529242</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>17375</td>
          <td>76026</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>733329</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>35406</td>
          <td>57995</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>746539</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>23206</td>
          <td>70195</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>735203</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>13457</td>
          <td>79944</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>647672</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>24084</td>
          <td>69317</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>602008</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>15717</td>
          <td>77684</td>
          <td>93401</td>
          <td>743478</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Cuando se ha ejecutado el bucle, `filas` tiene un contenido con la forma:

```
[
  {
    "cuotano": "1",
    "interes": "36364",
    "abonocapital": "57037",
    "valorcuota": "93401",
    "saldocapital": "553073"
  },
  {
    "cuotano": "2",
    "interes": "29456",
    "abonocapital": "63945",
    "valorcuota": "93401",
    "saldocapital": "622957"
  }
]
```

Y esto puedes enviarlo al backend haciendo:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "crud/register-payment-plan.php",
  data: {valores : JSON.stringify(filas) },
  success: function(data) { 
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```

En tu backend, recibes ese objeto como un string json_encoded, así que lo conviertes a un array de arrays asociativos:

```
 $filas = json_decode($_POST['valores'], true);
```

Ese arreglo tiene la forma:

```
[
    [
        'cuotano'      => 1,
        'interes'      => 36364,
        'abonocapital' => 57037,
        'valorcuota'   => 93401,
        'saldocapital' => 553073,
    ],
    [
        'cuotano'      => 2,
        'interes'      => 29456,
        'abonocapital' => 63945,
        'valorcuota'   => 93401,
        'saldocapital' => 622957,
    ],
    [
        'cuotano'      => 3,
        'interes'      => 17136,
        'abonocapital' => 76265,
        'valorcuota'   => 93401,
        'saldocapital' => 581032,
    ],
]
```

Ahora, para hacer las inserciones, recorres ese arreglo de arreglos, pero no interpolas manualmente las variables, sino que usas una sentencia preparada (*en este ejemplo voy a omitir el campo `payment_date_applied` porque no queda claro de dónde sale `$dates`*). La gracia es que sólo necesitas preparar el statement una sola vez, es mucho más eficiente.

```
include_once '../connection/connection.php';

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO payment_plan (
        loan_id,
        fee_number,
        tentative_payment_date,
        fee_value,
        pending_value,
        state
    ) VALUES (
        '16',
        ?,
        '2018-10-10',
        ?,
        ?,
        'pendiente'
    )");
```

Esa sentencia preparada tiene tres placeholders. Tú los bindeas a tres variables:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $cuotano, $valorcuota, $saldocapital);
```

Aunque... mirando tu tabla, pareciera que los campos son numéricos, así que mejor los casteas:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ddd', $cuotano, $valorcuota, $saldocapital);
```

Y luego iteras sobre los elementos del array `$filas` simplemente asignando valor a esas variables e invocando `execute`. Si la salida de `execute` es `true`, le añades 1 a un contador que al final informa la cantidad de registros insertados:

```
$inserciones = 0;
foreach ($filas as $fila) {
    $cuotano      = $fila['cuotano'];
    $valorcuota   = $fila['valorcuota'];
    $saldocapital = $fila['saldocapital'];
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if($result) {
        $inserciones++;
    }
}

echo "Se insertaron $inserciones registros";
```

Comment: he intentado,replicar esto y me inprime una lista de objetos vacios de esta forma, [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]  , a que se debera?

Comment: Significa que tienes un array de objetos. Si no haces un JSON.parse(datos) antes de tirar a la consola, así es como se ven los objetos casteados a string

Comment: Creo que es mejor que publiques tu propia pregunta, porque no tengo claro lo que preguntas